# how to correctly display a robot in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I successfully displayed my robot in rviz.

The problem is that the legs seem "inside" the grid.

The origin of my base is (0,0,0).
Do I have to use a height ?

I also found the description of a planar joint on the wiki.

Do I have to connect the legs to the grid ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64434/how-to-correctly-display-a-robot-in-rviz-?/) by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mentar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2076/mentar/) on 2013-06-09**:
What version of ROS and RVIZ are you using? I'm having similar issues with urdf_tutorials in groovy, basically all the tutorials are broken :(

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-06-13**:
@mentar: I'm on debian_amd64/sid with fuerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz will render your robot in whatever frame you ask for.  And the frame to which the grid is attached is also selectable.  If the origin of your robot is the frame into which rviz is rendering the grid will default to that frame.  Find the drop down menu for the grid to move it to a different frame. Or update the fixed frame in the rviz menu.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3